# bind commands to an ssh

Tags: linux, ssh

I'm new to this, wondering if someone could help.

I need to ssh to a server and bind commands to it, which copies a directory, zips it up etc..

`ssh user@123.45.67.89 ; cd /to/directory/ ; zip these files`

Something similar to the above.  If anyone could offer advice, would be a great help! Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You can append a command to `ssh`:

```
ssh user@123.45.67.89 "cd /to/directory/ ; gzip -r somedir > test.zip"
```

Be careful of string expansion:

Double quotes get expanded on the local machine.

```
ssh user@123.45.67.89 "gzip -r /var/www/$(hostname)/httpdocs > test.zip"
```

expands to: `gzip -r /var/www/localhostname/httpdocs > test.zip`

Single quotes get expanded on the remote machine.

```
ssh user@123.45.67.89 'gzip -r /var/www/$(hostname)/httpdocs > test.zip'
```

expands to: `gzip -r /var/www/remotehostname/httpdocs > test.zip`

Comment: Am I missing something, or did you re-draft the expansion examples and break them in the process?

Comment: @Jimbo nope, the examples above are correct, what's broken for you?

Comment: I don't see where the 'rm' or the '-rf' come from

Comment: ah that's alright, I was beginning to doubt my sanity!